# como avisar del pattern puesto html

Tags: html

Como puedo avisar de este pattern, Quiero decir cuando dice: " Utilice un formato que coincida con el solicitado, avisar de alguna forma al usuario de que debe de contener ese formato especifico

> pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,55}"

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- AUTOR: Alejandro M. Carrión K.
Programa: Calculadora-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Cifrado Cesar</title>
   

<head>

<body>

    <h1>Cifrado Cesar</h1>

    
    Mensaje a descifrar
    <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
    <select name="cifrado">

        <option value="cifrar">Cifrar</option>

        <option value="descifrar">Descifrar</option>

    </select>   

</select><br/>
       <!–  Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar ->
        
        <label for="texto">Texto a descrifrar o descifrar</label>
        <!–  filtrado de a-z y A-Z con espacios una palabra de 2 digitos
         y maximo un mensaje de 254 ->
        <input type="text" name="texto" size="55"  pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,55}"required>*<br />

        <label for="desplazamiento">desplazamiento</label>
        <input type="number" name="desplazamiento" min="1" size="4" required>*<br />


        <!–  Borrar los valores ->
        <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

        <!–  Recoger los datos ->
        <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: que estas tratando de avisar ? podrias poner un `<label>` para decirle lo que permites .. pero no se entiende muy bien la pregunta, te aconsejo que leas [ask] y modifiques tu pregunta para que te podamos ayudar mas facilmente

Comment: Quiero decir cuando dice: " Utilice un formato que coincida con el solicitado

Comment: ¿Quieres que diga eso o eso lo dice en alguna parte? En caso de la primera ¿Dónde quieres que lo diga? ¿En qué momento? Faltan muchos datos para poder formular una respuesta...

Comment: A ese input que tiene el pattern métele un placeholder seguidamente que ponga: `pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,55}" placeholder="Utilice un formato: [a-zA-Z ]{2,55}" required>` y saldrá en el propio input, sin que el usuario deba borrar texto para escribir, Utilice un formato: [a-zA-Z ]{2,55}. De todas formas no parece que en ningún lado compruebes que solo entren esos caracteres.

Comment: Puedes hacelo con JavaScript, con el método setCustomValidity().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te han comentado, puedes usar un `placeholder` y poner el mensaje que quieres que vea el usuario.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- AUTOR: Alejandro M. Carrión K.
Programa: Calculadora-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Cifrado Cesar</title>
   

<head>

<body>

    <h1>Cifrado Cesar</h1>

    
    Mensaje a descifrar
    <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
    <select name="cifrado">

        <option value="cifrar">Cifrar</option>

        <option value="descifrar">Descifrar</option>

    </select>   

</select><br/>
       <!–  Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar ->
        
        <label for="texto">Texto a descrifrar o descifrar</label>
        <!–  filtrado de a-z y A-Z con espacios una palabra de 2 digitos
         y maximo un mensaje de 254 ->
        <input type="text" name="texto" size="55" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,55}" placeholder="Solo se permiten 55 caracteres" required>*<br />

        <label for="desplazamiento">desplazamiento</label>
        <input type="number" name="desplazamiento" min="1" size="4" required>*<br />


        <!–  Borrar los valores ->
        <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

        <!–  Recoger los datos ->
        <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Aun que está bien la respuesta, si te fijas, no es exacta la pregunta, por eso no lo puse yo como respuesta. Ante preguntas tan amplias es mejor pedir al usuario que matice. No sabes si era esto o preguntaba por una comprobación del formulario con JS o jQuery y si no cumplia que saliera esto.